# Object got distorted when exported to FBX

Tags: animation, mesh, export, .fbx, surface-deform

I'm making an animation from online tutorial about opening a book. I exported it to FBX file for Unreal but then the object got distorted after exporting. What should I do to fix it?
This is the before after exporting.
[image]

Comment: Did you apply the scale (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) to all the objects in your file before exporting?

Comment: it's probably what John suggested, but in case that doesn't work, could you please upload the file to https://blend-exchange.com/